# Como criar vários arquivos .txt?

Tags: c, c++

Como faço para criar vários arquivos .txt em c/c++ ?
Tenho essa função:

```
tocopy(){
    FILE *file = fopen("Teste.txt", "w");
    fclose(file);
}
```

Porém ela só cria um arquivo Teste.txt

Comment: C ou C++? São linguagens diferentes, com soluções próprias diferentes.

Comment: Para criar arquivos diferentes você deve chamar `fopen` com nomes de arquivos diferentes.... Por favor explique melhor o seu problema para podermos dar uma resposta mais satisfatória.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em C, podes, por exemplo, fazer um loop dentro do qual geras nomes de ficheiros diferentes. Se criares sempre um ficheiro com o mesmo nome, o Sistema Operativo só vai guardar o ficheiro mais recente.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void tocopy(void) {
    int k;
    for (k = 0; k < 100; k++) {
        char filename[100];
        FILE *file;
        sprintf(filename, "Teste-%02d.txt", k); /* Teste-00.txt; Teste-01.txt; ...; Teste-99.txt */
        file = fopen(filename, "w");
        if (file != NULL) {
            fclose(file);
        } else {
            perror(filename);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Acho genial quando alguem simplesmente responde a pergunta! e de maneira objetiva!   Nos iniciantes que temos dificuldades em formular  perguntas agradecemos!!!!, Obrigado @pmg!